# wkhtmltopdf Error Code 193

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have downloaded the binary file for wkhtmltopdf but when I try to call the function to create a PDF I get:

```
( ! ) Warning: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 193 in V:\wamp\www\libs\WkHtmlToPdf.php on line 300
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  264048  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0074  1589152 Router->__construct( )  ..\index.php:89
3   0.0085  1640944 Pdfe->index( )  ..\Router.php:122
4   15.5444 1731712 WkHtmlToPdf->send( )    ..\pdfe.php:25
5   15.5444 1731864 WkHtmlToPdf->getPdfFilename( )  ..\WkHtmlToPdf.php:187
6   15.5446 1732112 WkHtmlToPdf->createPdf( )   ..\WkHtmlToPdf.php:280
7   15.5446 1734016 proc_open ( )   ..\WkHtmlToPdf.php:300
```

My research shows that error 193 is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`. My OS is Windows Server 2008 64bit.

My bin line is:

```
class WkHtmlToPdf
{
    protected $bin = 'V:\wamp\www\libs\wkhtmltopdf-i386';
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a list of error codes : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It appears to be a non-valid Win32 application. Maybe you installed the wrong bit version?